# How to bring equal elements together using thrust without sort

Tags: cuda, thrust

I have an array of elements such that each element defines the "equal to" operator only.
In other words no ordering is defined for such type of element.

Since I can't use thrust::sort  as in the thrust histogram example how can I bring equal elements together using thrust?

For example:

my array is initially

```
a e t b c a c e t a
```

where identical characters represent equal elements.

After the elaboration, the array should be

```
a a a t t b c c e e
```

but it can be also

```
a a a c c t t e e b
```

or any other permutation.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal you are trying to solve? Creating a histogram or just sorting?

Comment: @m.s my ultimate goal is to reorder the array so that  equal elements  are consecutive

Comment: What kind of elements do you try to reorder? Is it possible to define a `less` operator outside of the struct/class?

Comment: @m.s no "less" operator can be defined

Comment: Because of what? High dimensionality? Can you please give an example of the elements? Can you define a hash function to identify equal elements?

Comment: @m.s. An element is simply a float4. Now  I have a function with two float4 as input parameters and a single float as output. The output can be a number greater than 1 or almost 0. So I defined the "equal to" operator so that it returns true when the output is  zero and false when the output is a number  greater than 1. I don't know how to define for this kind of data a less operator or a hash function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74506/discussion-between-m-s-and-bc547).

Comment: It's possible to group like elements without using sorting/ordering of the elements, but it's expensive. The advantage of sorting/ordering is that it provides substantial reduction in algorithm complexity, which is why @m.s. is trying to guide you in that direction. To be clear, for grouping purposes, you **can** use sorting even if it resorts to  enumerating (or hashing) your elements and then assign an arbitrary order to them. So you are well advised to investigate ordering. I have worked out a method to group elements without ordering, but it's ugly. If you wish to see it, I can present it.

Comment: Ok, I will investigate if some sort of ordering may be plausible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend that you follow an approach such as that laid out by @m.s. in the posted answer there.  As I stated in the comments, ordering of elements is an extremely useful mechanism that aids in the reduction of complexity for problems like this.

However the question as posed asks if it is possible to group like elements without sorting.    With an inherently parallel processor like a GPU, I spent some time thinking about how it might be accomplished without sorting.

If we have both a large number of objects, as well as a large number of unique object types, then I think it's possible to bring some level of parallelism to the problem, *however* my approach outlined here will still have atrocious, scattered memory access patterns.  For the case where there are only a small number of distinct or unique object types, the algorithm I am discussing here has little to commend it.  This is just one possible approach.  There may well be other, far better approaches:

1. The starting point is to develop a set of "linked lists" that indicate the matching neighbor to the left and the matching neighbor to the right, for each element.  This is accomplished via my `search_functor` and `thrust::for_each`, on the entire data set.  This step is reasonably parallel and also has reasonable memory access efficiency for large data sets, but it does require a worst-case traversal of the entire data set from start to finish (a side-effect, I would call it, of not being able to use ordering; we must compare every element to other elements until we find a match).  The generation of two linked lists allows us to avoid all-to-all comparisons.
2. Once we have the lists (right-neighbor and left-neighbor) built from step 1, it's an easy matter to count the number of unique objects, using `thrust::count`.
3. We then get the starting indexes of each unique element (i.e. the leftmost index of each type of unique element, in the dataset), using `thrust::copy_if` stream compaction.
4. The next step is to count the number of instances of each of the unique elements.   This step is doing list traversal, one thread per element list.   If I have a small number of unique elements, this will not effectively utilize the GPU.  In addition, the list traversal will result in lousy access patterns.
5. After we have counted the number of each type of object, we can then build a sequence of starting indices for each object type in the output list, via `thrust::exclusive_scan` on the numbers of each type of object.
6. Finally, we can copy each input element to it's appropriate place in the output list.  Since we have no way to group or order the elements yet, we must again resort to list traversal.  Once again, this will be inefficient use of the GPU if the number of unique object types is small, and will also have lousy memory access patterns.

Here's a fully worked example, using your sample data set of characters.  To help clarify the idea that we intend to group objects that have no inherent ordering, I have created a somewhat arbitrary object definition (`my_obj`), that has the `==` comparison operator defined, but no definition for `<` or `>`.

```
$ cat t707.cu
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/for_each.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/transform_scan.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/count.h>
#include <iostream>


template <typename T>
class my_obj
{
  T element;
  int index;
  public:
  __host__ __device__ my_obj() : element(0), index(0) {};
  __host__ __device__ my_obj(T a) : element(a), index(0) {};
  __host__ __device__ my_obj(T a, int idx) : element(a), index(idx) {};
  __host__ __device__
  T get() {
    return element;}
  __host__ __device__
  void set(T a) {
    element = a;}
  __host__ __device__
  int get_idx() {
    return index;}
  __host__ __device__
  void set_idx(int idx) {
    index = idx;}
  __host__ __device__
  bool operator ==(my_obj &e2)
  {
    return (e2.get() == this->get());
  }
};

template <typename T>
struct search_functor
{
    my_obj<T> *data;
    int end;
    int *rn;
    int *ln;
    search_functor(my_obj<T> *_a, int *_rn, int *_ln, int len) : data(_a), rn(_rn), ln(_ln), end(len) {};
    __host__ __device__
    void operator()(int idx){
      for (int i = idx+1; i < end; i++)
        if (data[idx] == data[i]) {
          ln[i] = idx;
          rn[idx] = i;
          return;}
      return;
      }
};

template <typename T>
struct copy_functor
{
    my_obj<T> *data;
    my_obj<T> *result;
    int *rn;
    copy_functor(my_obj<T> *_in, my_obj<T> *_out, int *_rn) : data(_in), result(_out), rn(_rn) {};
    __host__ __device__
    void operator()(const thrust::tuple<int, int> &t1) const {
      int idx1 = thrust::get<0>(t1);
      int idx2 = thrust::get<1>(t1);
      result[idx1] = data[idx2];
      int i = rn[idx2];
      int j = 1;
      while (i != -1){
        result[idx1+(j++)] = data[i];
        i = rn[i];}
      return;
      }
};

struct count_functor
{
    int *rn;
    int *ot;
    count_functor(int *_rn, int *_ot) : rn(_rn), ot(_ot) {};
    __host__ __device__
    int operator()(int idx1, int idx2){
      ot[idx1] = idx2;
      int i = rn[idx1];
      int count = 1;
      while (i != -1) {
        ot[i] = idx2;
        count++;
        i = rn[i];}
      return count;
      }
};

using namespace thrust::placeholders;

int main(){

  // data setup
  char data[] = { 'a' ,  'e' ,  't' ,  'b' ,  'c' ,  'a' ,  'c' , 'e' ,  't' ,  'a' };
  int sz = sizeof(data)/sizeof(char);
  for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) std::cout << data[i] << ",";
  std::cout << std::endl;
  thrust::host_vector<my_obj<char> > h_data(sz);
  for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) { h_data[i].set(data[i]); h_data[i].set_idx(i); }
  thrust::device_vector<my_obj<char> > d_data = h_data;


  // create left and right neighbor indices
  thrust::device_vector<int> ln(d_data.size(), -1);
  thrust::device_vector<int> rn(d_data.size(), -1);
  thrust::for_each(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0) + sz, search_functor<char>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_data.data()), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(rn.data()), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(ln.data()), d_data.size()));
  // determine number of unique objects
  int uni_objs = thrust::count(ln.begin(), ln.end(), -1);
  // determine the number of instances of each unique object
    // get object starting indices
  thrust::device_vector<int> uni_obj_idxs(uni_objs);
  thrust::copy_if(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0)+d_data.size(), ln.begin(), uni_obj_idxs.begin(), (_1 == -1));
    // count each object list
  thrust::device_vector<int> num_objs(uni_objs);
  thrust::device_vector<int> obj_type(d_data.size());
  thrust::transform(uni_obj_idxs.begin(), uni_obj_idxs.end(), thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0),  num_objs.begin(), count_functor(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(rn.data()), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(obj_type.data())));

  // at this point, we have built object lists that have allowed us to identify a unique, orderable "type" for each object
  // the sensible thing to do would be to employ a sort_by_key on obj_type and an index sequence at this point
  // and use the reordered index sequence to reorder the original objects, thus grouping them
  // however...  without sorting...

  // build output vector indices
  thrust::device_vector<int> copy_start(num_objs.size());
  thrust::exclusive_scan(num_objs.begin(), num_objs.end(), copy_start.begin());
  // copy (by object type) input to output
  thrust::device_vector<my_obj<char> > d_result(d_data.size());
  thrust::for_each(thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(copy_start.begin(), uni_obj_idxs.begin())), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(copy_start.end(), uni_obj_idxs.end())), copy_functor<char>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_data.data()), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_result.data()), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(rn.data())));

  // display results
  std::cout << "Grouped: " << std::endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < d_data.size(); i++){
    my_obj<char> temp = d_result[i];
    std::cout << temp.get() << ",";}
  std::cout << std::endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < d_data.size(); i++){
    my_obj<char> temp = d_result[i];
    std::cout << temp.get_idx() << ",";}
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t707 t707.cu
$ ./t707
a,e,t,b,c,a,c,e,t,a,
Grouped:
a,a,a,e,e,t,t,b,c,c,
0,5,9,1,7,2,8,3,4,6,
$
```

Comment: why don't you just use thrust::sort_by_key in the 6 step  using as keys the obj_type vector? Could this improve memory access pattern ?

Comment: Certainly you can, and that was the reason for the creation of the `obj_type` vector, as well as my extensive comment in the code that the right thing to do would be sort_by_key.  But the problem statement says "without sort".

Answer (score 2):

[In the discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74506/discussion-between-m-s-and-bc547) we found out that your real goal is to eliminate duplicates in a vector of `float4` elements.
In order to apply [thrust::unique](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__stream__compaction.html#ga76d09b803bb439fa86b12de43d4fdcf8) the elements need to be sorted.

So you need a sort method for 4 dimensional data. This can be done using space-filling curves. I have previously used the [z-order curve (aka morton code)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) to sort 3D data. There are efficient CUDA implementations for the [3D case available](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/thinking-parallel-part-iii-tree-construction-gpu/), however quick googling did not return a ready-to-use implementation for the 4D case.

I found a paper which lists a generic algorithm for sorting n-dimensional data points using the z-order curve:
[Fast construction of k-Nearest Neighbor Graphs for Point Clouds](http://compgeom.com/%7Epiyush/papers/tvcg_stann.pdf)
(see Algorithm 1 : Floating Point Morton Order Algorithm).
There is also a [C++ implementation available](https://sites.google.com/a/compgeom.com/stann/) for this algorithm.

For 4D data, the loop could be unrolled, but there might be simpler and more efficient algorithms available.

So the (not fully implemented) sequence of operations would then look like this:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/unique.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>

inline __host__ __device__ float dot(const float4& a, const float4& b)
{
    return a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y + a.z * b.z + a.w * b.w;
}

struct identity_4d
{
  __host__ __device__
  bool operator()(const float4& a, const float4& b) const
  {
    // based on the norm function you provided in the discussion
    return dot(a,b) < (0.1f*0.1f);
  }
};

struct z_order_4d
{
  __host__ __device__
  bool operator()(const float4& p, const float4& q) const
  {
    // you need to implement the z-order algorithm here
    // ...
  }
};

int main()
{
  const int N = 100;
  thrust::device_vector<float4> data(N);
  // fill the data
  // ...

  thrust::sort(data.begin(),data.end(), z_order_4d());

  thrust::unique(data.begin(),data.end(), identity_4d());

}
```

Comment: sorry but this doesn't solve the problem, because  there will sometimes be points where the coordinates are close but their z-curve values are far apart.

Comment: can you give some concrete examples?